# Why is node.appendChild() not working?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, methods, appendchild

I have this bit of code that's later going to be used to spit out the dates in a calendar. I'm trying to do this dynamically so I can load in the dates from the current month. I'm using reactjs and I keep getting an error that appendChild is not a function. I don't see what's wrong here, according to the docs its looks correct. [See documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node/appendChild)

```
let datesContainer = document.getElementById('display')

function drawCalendar() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
    let dateNode = document.createElement("div")
    dateNode.textContent = toString(i)
    dateNode.setAttribute("id", "dateNode" + i)
    datesContainer.appendChild(dateNode)
  }
}
drawCalendar()

class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="display">
          <div className="d-numbers" id="display">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Is `datesContainer` a valid HTML element?

Comment: not showing `datesContainer` being defined is making this hard to answer.

Comment: Now with the edit, are you sure it is found? `console.log(datesContainer);`

Comment: I accidentally didn't copy it in, but to answer the question it is an html element.

Comment: when trying `console.log(datesContainer)` it came up not defined. In my terminal though I get the output message: 'datesContainer' is assigned a value but never used

Comment: try calling `drawCalendar()` inside a componentDidMount() lifecycle method

Comment: @Derek Thanks for the suggestion but it didn't work :(

Comment: including the call to document.getElementById() - the element is not yet in the DOM before React mounts the component.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I suppose this is a Reactjs specific thing or just the timing on how the code is executed. As you can see with @MarkBaijens answer the code does work in vanilla js. @Derek Led me to the solution which was to put my function and DOM element inside a `componentDidMount()` method. In react the place initialize a variable with a DOM node is inside that method [see documentation](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount).

```
class App extends Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    let datesContainer = document.getElementById('display')

    function drawCalendar() {
      for (let i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
        let dateNode = document.createElement("div")
        dateNode.textContent = i
        dateNode.setAttribute("id", "dateNode" + i)
        datesContainer.appendChild(dateNode)
      }
    }
    drawCalendar()
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="display">
          <div className="d-numbers" id="display">

          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You where using the `tostring()` function the wrong way. You don't need that at all to be honest. Javascript does that automatically.

```js
let datesContainer = document.getElementById('display');

function drawCalendar() {
  for (let i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
    let dateNode = document.createElement("div");
    dateNode.textContent = i;
    dateNode.setAttribute("id", "dateNode" + i);
    datesContainer.appendChild(dateNode);
  }
}
drawCalendar();
```

```html
<div id="display"></div>
```

Comment: but the error he is getting is differrent, that is, `appendChild is not a function`

Comment: @McRist This was the only error in this piece of code. `appendChild` is working fine as you can see. If he got more errors then we need all related code to debug.

Comment: This is the result I want but when copying your code I'm getting the error: Cannot read property 'appendChild' of null. Maybe this is a react specific thing?

Answer (score 0):

This should work for you:

```
class App extends Component {
  makeCalendarDates = () => {
    const dates = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < 42; i++) {
      const nodeId = `dateNode${i}`;
      dates.push(<div id={nodeId} key={nodeId}>${i}</div>);
    }
    return dates;
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <div className="display">
          <div className="d-numbers" id="display">
            {this.makeCalendarDates()}
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```